# Loopback environment specific middleware is not working

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, loopbackjs

I am following [loopback environment specific configuration](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Environment-specific+configuration#Environment-specificconfiguration-Overview) to refer environment specific config, data sources and middleware json files.

When I push my app to a staging server, `NODE_ENV` environment variable gets set to `staging` and based on this variable `config.staging.json` and `datasources.staging.json` files are referred but NOT `middleware.staging.json`.

Here is the complete content of `middleware.json` file:

```
{
  "initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {}
  },
  "initial": {
    "compression": {},
    "cors": {
      "params": {
        "origin": true,
        "credentials": true,
        "maxAge": 86400
      }
    }
  },
  "session": {},
  "auth": {},
  "parse": {},
  "routes": {},
  "files": {
      "loopback#static": [
        {
          "params": "$!../client/WebApp/www"
        }
      ]
  },
  "final": {
    "loopback#urlNotFound": {}
  },
  "final:after": {
    "errorhandler": {}
  }
}
```

and I would like to refer `middleware.staging.json` file whose complete content is:

```
{
  "files": {
    "loopback#static": [
      {
        "params": "$!../client/WebApp/dist"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to change the target folder from `www` to `dist`. It seems `middleware.staging.json` file is not referred and `middleware.json` file is always referred irrespective of `NODE_ENV` variable.

Am I creating environment specific middleware file correctly? Any alternates to achieve this?

Comment: You seem to be defining the environment variable correctly since it uses staging for config and datasources.

Comment: You could try to modify the entire middleware.json file into middleware.staging.json, then change in middleware.staging.json the properties you want to change. See if that changes something

Comment: I tried by putting the entire content of `middleware.json`  to `middleware.staging.json` but it doesn't work.

I was trying this on heroku server and also verified that it doesn't work locally as well.

Comment: Can you share a minimal project to see if I can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I solved it using this code in server.js:  
    `var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    console.log('environment: %s', environment);
    if (environment === 'staging' || environment === 'production') {
      app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/WebApp/dist')));
    } else {
      app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/WebApp/www')));
    }`
  
I'll try for a minimal project to reproduce the issue over the weekend. 

Sorry for the bad formatting and no line breaks. I need to learn. Putting four spaces didn't format the code.

Comment: I can confirm this issue with loopback v2.39.1. The middleware.production.json seems not to be taken into account at all.